# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error message

Tags: java, sql, swing

I try to select a row and store the row value into topicId using a jTable. Then, I use the topicId which I get just now to retrieve the data from database. Here are my codes.

```
    jTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                if (jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 0) != null) {
                    int topicId = (Integer)jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 0);}
                eForumTopics topics = new eForumTopics(topicId);
                topics.retrieveThread();
                getJFrame().dispose();
                eForumThreadContent myWindow = new eForumThreadContent(topicId);
                myWindow.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

However, I getting this error message.

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at kioskeForum.ui.eForumDiscussion$3.mouseClicked(eForumDiscussion.java:295)
```

Line 295 is the if statement there. I do not get what's wrong with my codes as I did not see any array. Can somebody fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them - _now_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `jTable.getSelectedRow()` returns `-1` which is not a valid parameter for `jTable.getValueAt()`. This can happen if no row in the jtable is selected.

From the documentation:

> Returns the index of the first selected row, -1 if no row is selected.

You should update your condition to something like:

```
if (jTable.getSelectedRow() >= 0 && jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 0) != null) {
```

Comment: Does the if statement same as these codes? int topicId = jTable.getSelectedRow(); . I mean does both of them serve the same purpose to get the number of selected row and store into topicId?

Comment: But why it keeps returning the value of 0 to me even when I clicked on the second n third row of table?